# Managing ajax calls with jQuery Deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to check the availability of internet access in a device at a given point of time. So, I am making an ajax call to the server to load a tiny image. I came across jQuery Deferred and tried to use it.

```
var spacer = "some url";
var getImage;
var connectionAlive;
function checkOnline(spacer) {
    getImage = $.ajax({url:spacer})
                .done(function() {console.log('Connection alive');connectionAlive = true;})
                .fail(function() {console.log('Connection dead');connectionAlive = false;});
    if(connectionAlive === true) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now i have to call this checkOnline function when certain events occur. So, i am calling the function and waiting till the promise is resolved.

```
$(document).on('click','#explore',function() {
    checkOnline(spacer);
    getImage.done(function() {
            // Do something
            })
 });
```

This only works the first time and I think it is because the deferred object state stays the same once it is resolved. How should I write my code so that i can actually check the connection every-time the click event fires?

New Code:

Hi, I followed the above code but still the click event is only working correctly the first time.

```
    var connectionAlive;
var url = "http://example.com";
function checkOnline(url, callback1,callback2) {
    $.ajax({url:url})
        .done(function() {console.log('Connection alive');connectionAlive = true;})
        .done(callback1)
        .fail(function() {console.log('Connection dead');connectionAlive = false;})
        .fail(callback2);

}

$(document).on('click','#explore',function() {
    checkOnline(url, function(){
        console.log('Connection Alive from event');
    },function() {
        console.log('Connection Dead from event');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `checkOnline` to return the promise itself:

```
$(document).on('click','#explore',function() {
     checkOnline('url.com').done(function(){
          // Do something
     });
});

var connectionAlive;
function checkOnline(url) {
    return $.ajax({url : url})
            .done(function() {console.log('Connection alive');connectionAlive = true;})
            .fail(function() {console.log('Connection dead');connectionAlive = false;});
}
```

Or change it to take a callback:

```
$(document).on('click','#explore',function() {
     checkOnline('url.com', function(){
          // Do something
     });
});

var connectionAlive;
function checkOnline(url, callback) {
    $.ajax({ url : url})
     .done(function() {console.log('Connection alive');connectionAlive = true;})
     .done(callback)
     .fail(function() {console.log('Connection dead');connectionAlive = false;});
     // Do not try to return connectionAlive from here,
     // it will return the value before the ajax response arrived
}
```

Comment: Hi, I followed the above code but still the click event is only working correctly the first time.

Comment: Strange. Both versions work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jCkmT/ (*fail* message logged on every click)

Comment: For the first time when i click the #explore, i am getting the connection alive msg. Then, when i remove the image from the location and try the click again, it is still giving a Connection Alive status.

Comment: Im not sure if i'm correct but i'm thinking the fiddle will still deliver a Connection Dead message even if we give it a valid URL. Not sure how to check it though.

Comment: Now I understand it. Removing the image won't kill the connection (shutting down your network would). It will return a 404, which is a `success` status for jQuery. So your `done` callback is always executed. About the fiddle: it's by design, it's a security restriction (same origin policy).

Comment: Aha... Thank you. Any ideas on a better way to detect the internet access than loading a remote image?

Comment: That's fine, just hit the smallest file possible. But nothing is fail proof, it may fail even if the internet is up. So after a fail you should schedule a recheck. On a side note, your original code should work, but consider the cleaner alternatives I gave.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13198/discussion-between-sparda-and-bfavaretto)